# When testing my PWA on Android/iOS, what is the best way to simulate what happens when the app has been closed/unused for a day or two?

Tags: android, ios, laravel, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

I've just recently set up my SPA (Laravel/Vue) as a PWA and so far it seems to work pretty well on Android/iOS. Only problem is that I get some issues when first opening the app after it hasn't been used in a day or two.

Regardless of the exact error, what is the best way to simulate the app having been closed/untouched for a day or two on Android and/or iOS? I can't afford to wait that long every time I want to see how leaving it untouched affects the behavior of my app.

As a side note, since it is a Laravel 5.8 app, I tried opening up `config/session.php` and setting `lifetime` to `1` minute before the session expires, but this doesn't really give the full effect I'm going for, because Android/iOS seems to automatically force a refresh of the page on the client side, when opening the app again after a certain amount of time has passed (plus other stuff, like probably expiring temporary cookies, session data, but possibly leaving cache untouched, etc, who knows?).

I'd like force my mobile device to do everything it normally does in this case without having to wait. Is there some way to do this directly on either Android or iOS? (Or perhaps simulate on Chrome desktop?)